# Run an external command on page request

Tags: apache, apache2, analytics

#### Problem

I have an Apache server, and I'm trying to add my own custom analytics to it.  What I want is to have the server call a script whenever a page is requested, and for that script to record the requested URL.

If it's not possible to run an external command, I'd want Apache to POST to a URL to record the page visit.

#### Research

I've tried searching for a way to run an external command from Apache, but everything I've seen is a CGI script.  I don't want to change how Apache handles the URL, I just want a way to give it to a script to record it.

#### Question

Is there a way I can have Apache run an external command or POST to a URL whenever a page is requested?

Answer (score 0):

Apache already records the URL for every request - in the access log. Further, its [trivial to drop in a filter script](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/rotatelogs.html) between Apache and the file if you want to trigger more complex and specific side effects.

> I don't want to change how Apache handles the URL

Why do you believe using a script handler (no sane person uses CGI nowadays) will change the way the request is handled?

Perhaps if you explained why you want to record the URL you might get more appropriate answers.

Comment: What is a script handler?  All the answers I found related to this used CGI scripts, that's why I specified that the page should return as it currently does.

Comment: I want to record the URL for analytics, so I can keep track of how many times a particular URL gets visited.  Modifying the pages returned is not an option

Comment: If you Google `apache "script handler"`, the first two results are about CGI.  If you have links to information about how to properly use handlers, I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: Nope. In 2018 the first 2 I get are creating a mapping in npm (file inclusion) and the second is for integrating an ISAPI interface. The 6th one is about CGI. Handlers integrate in different ways. But from what you've said you should be using your logs.